# Is There performance difference between this three function return ways (c++)

Tags: c++

```
A Function1()
{
    return {1};
}

A Function2()
{
    return A{1};
}

A Function3()
{
    A a{1};
    return a;
}
```

i tried three ways. they all call just one assignment constructor.

i question There can be performance difference depending on which complier to use?

Comment: That's a separate question

Comment: For performance questions you should check out [quick-bench.com](https://quick-bench.com/q/i_9XYmoKTFwjNFLuVk-7SkBgCtY).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are subtle differences:

- `Function1` requires non explicit `A`'s constructor.
  construct `A` "in place" (even before C++17). so copy/move A's constructor might even be marked as `= delete`, and program is well formed.
- pre-C++17, `Function2` will use move/copy constructor which might be elided (return value optimization: RVO) (copy/move constructor should be available though (marking as `= delete` won't compile)).
  Post C++17, no move/copy are done (similar to `Function1`, but work with `explicit` constructors).
- `Function3` will use move/copy constructor which might be elided (named return value optimization: NRVO).

With correct options, compilers will do the optimization, and all should be equivalent.

With options such as `-fno-elide-constructors`, pre-c++17, `Function1` should win, post C++17, `Function1` and `Function2` should win.

Answer (score 3):

The first two are identical, they will construct and return the object using `A(1)`.

The last one, without NRVO, will create the object on the stack then copy-construct it to return. With NRVO it should be the same as the other two.